# How to use json with neo4j

Tags: json, neo4j

I am new to neo4j and json, is there any specific tutorial to use json with neo4j? I went through the neo4j documentation, but I couldn't find any help there.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the REST API:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api.html